# Meteor how to get access to Facebook Graph Api for both Server and Client side

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor, meteor-accounts

[accounts-facebook](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-facebook) package provides only logIn and logOut functionality.

[meteor-fbgraph](https://github.com/stevezhu/meteor-fbgraph) gives access to fbgraph on server side.

[facebook-sdk](https://atmospherejs.com/biasport/facebook-sdk) gives access to fbgraph on client side.

The problem is that facebook-sdk doesn't use anything provided with Accounts-ui, such as `Accounts.onLogin` event or `Accounts.ui.config`. After click on `{{> loginButtons}}` when user is logged in only `Meteor.user()` does log out, `facebook-sdk` still has it's AccessToken and remains logged in. In the result half of the application remains logged in (client) and half logged out (server).

Here is my workaround by pairing Accounts with FB events, but I think it's not a proper solution.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){
  FB.login();
  AccountsOnLogout(function(){
    FB.logout();
  });
});

function AccountsOnLogout(callback){
  var waitForLogout = setInterval(function() {
    if (!(Meteor.user())) {
      console.log("logged out");
      callback();
      clearInterval(waitForLogout);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Do You have any better idea how to get to fbGraph on client side?

Answer (score 6):

I am using only "kinda workaround" for you, cause I would be manipulating and caching respond data on the server anyway. So I just call methods and use that server side.

```
Facebook = (accessToken) ->
  @fb = Meteor.npmRequire 'fbgraph'
  @accessToken = accessToken
  @fb.setAccessToken @accessToken
  @options =
    timeout: 3000
    pool:
      maxSockets: Infinity
    headers:
      connection: "keep-alive"
  @fb.setOptions @options


FBQuery = (query, method, fbObject) ->
  if typeof method is 'undefined' then method = 'get'
  console.log "query is: " + query
  data = Meteor.sync((done) ->
    fbObject[method](query, (err, res) ->
      done(null, res)
    )
  )
  data.result


Meteor.methods(
  getUserData: ->
    fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken)
    FBQuery '/me', 'get', fb

  getUserEvents: ->
    fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken)
    FBQuery '/' + Meteor.user().services.facebook.id + '/events', 'get', fb

  getUserGroups: ->
    fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken)
    FBQuery '/' + Meteor.user().services.facebook.id + '/groups?fields=name&limit=1000', 'get', fb
)
```

And client side

```
Template.home.events(
  'click #btn-user-data': (e) ->
    Meteor.call('getUserData', (err, data) ->
      $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4))
    )
)
```